# How can I call ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync from startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, identity, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to upgrade one of the projects I'm working on to use the Microsoft.Identity.Web nuget package. So far really working well but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add additional claims which I was previously doing by the following:

```
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
            {
                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var distributedCache = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();

                var identifier = ctx.Principal.FindFirst(ObjectIdentifierType)?.Value;

                var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions()
                {
                    ClientId = "ClientId",
                    RedirectUri = "RedirectUri",
                    ClientSecret = "ClientSecret"
                })
                .WithAuthority(ctx.Options.Authority)
                .Build();

                var tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(identifier, distributedCache);
                tokenCache.Initialize(cca.UserTokenCache);
                var token = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(token.AccessToken, token.IdToken);

                // get the claims
                var claimService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClaimService>();
                var response = await apiClient.GetUserAdditionalClaimsAsync(token.AccessToken);
                
                // add the claims
            };
```

Now when I try to use the ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync() method instead of using the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftWebApp(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options);
        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var tokenAcquisition = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();


            var token = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync("scopes");

            // get the claims
            var claimService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClaimService>();
            var response = await apiClient.GetUserAdditionalClaimsAsync(token);

            // add the claims
        };
    })
    .AddMicrosoftWebAppCallsWebApi(Configuration, new[] { "scopes" })
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

Any help would be so much appreciated on how best to handle this.
Thanks!

I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? It explains how to handle this for a Blazor application.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for commenting. Its not a Blazor app which further confuses me but which documentation do you mean? can you link it?

Comment: Not sure if it will give you an answer, but there's a thread on GitHub about this exception: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/115

Comment: @SuemayahEldursi Did you ever resolve this as I'm facing same issues?

Comment: @sam no unfortunately not yet. But I have opened a Github issue here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/460 hope that helps

Comment: Not completely sure about your use case but I solved mine with this sample available here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups/Startup.cs

Answer (score 3):

You use the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) when using `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`. I don't know why you use the ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync() to instead.

You can use the below [code sample](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) for client credential flow :

```
// Even if this is a console application here, a daemon application is a confidential client application
IConfidentialClientApplication app;

app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
        .WithTenantId("{tenantID}")
        .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
        .Build();

// With client credentials flows the scopes is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the
// application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal or by PowerShell), and then granted by
// a tenant administrator
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch(MsalServiceException ex)
{
// Case when ex.Message contains:
// AADSTS70011 Invalid scope. The scope has to be of the form "https://resourceUrl/.default"
// Mitigation: change the scope to be as expected
}
```