# Does Microsoft Identity Platform support Azure Active Directory App's client secrets out of the box?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I created a new ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web application using Visual Studio 2022, and I define it to use Azure AD for authentication, as follows:

[image]

[image]

Then I was asked to create an owned application, so I created one named "ad" as follows:

[image]

[image]

Inside my application's `appsetting.json` I have these settings:

```
{
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "*****",
        "TenantId": "***",
        "ClientId": "***",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
    ....
}
```

It seems Visual Studio did all the work for us.

But when I checked the "Certificate & Secrets" in the Azure portal for the generated Azure AD APP, I found that there is not anything assigned:

[image: ![enter image description here](/api/attachments/b6569579-d324-43c7-86a0-ff57ce1783ca?platform=QnA)]

So now we are going to generate a client secret, but not sure what i need to modify inside my ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0 to pass the client secret ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> So now we are going to generate a client secret, but not sure what i need to modify inside my ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0 to pass the client secret ?

The Microsoft Identity Platform does not necessarily require the use of a client secret for all scenarios, but it is an option for securing access to resources protected by a web API.

This means if you don't select the add permission to another API or graph api, it will not generate the secret, since this is no need.

Normally, if the application is a single-page app running in a browser and using an access token obtained through an interactive login.

> (if i do not specify any client secret) my Azure Active Directory app can be called by anonymous users?

It's impossible, if you set th authetnication tag inside your application's controller like this, this will only let authentication user access the controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

> do you know how i can pass the client secret from my asp.net core mvc to Azure AD app incase i specify a client secret ?

The client secret is used to generate the server to sever aces token, if you want to use it, you could try it like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407343/7609093).

Comment: thanks a lot for the great reply and info.. but in this case (if i do not specify any client secret) my Azure Active Directory app can be called by anonymous users? am i correct? second question, do you  know how i can pass the client secret from my asp.net core mvc to Azure AD app incase i specify a client secret ?

Comment: The question I have answerde inside my updated questions, all in all if you want to use secrect to access the web api, you could use package to use it to get the access token.